# Subset dataframe to contain only cells that match a pattern in r

Tags: r, filtering, subset

I am begginer in R and this is a very simple question, but I can't find the answer.

I would like to select cells in a table that match a particular pattern and exclude everything else.

Example data:

```
data.t <- data.frame(ColA = c("NARG_ECOLI^Q:103", "NARG_ECOLI^NARG", "SPEB_KLEP7^Q:103"), ColB = c(NA, NA, NA), ColC = c("KLEP7^Q:103", "NARG_ECOLI^KLEP7", NA), ColD = c("RPOC_ENTFA^Q:2", NA, NA), ColE = c("Y1546_STAS1^Q:6", NA, NA))
```

which generates a table like this:

```
              ColA ColB             ColC           ColD ColE
1 NARG_ECOLI^Q:103   NA      KLEP7^Q:103 RPOC_ENTFA^Q:2   NA
2  NARG_ECOLI^NARG   NA NARG_ECOLI^KLEP7           <NA>   NA
3 SPEB_KLEP7^Q:103   NA             <NA>           <NA>   NA
```

I would like to select only cells containing ECOLI. Thus, the desired output would look like this one:

```
              ColA             ColC
1 NARG_ECOLI^Q:103 NARG_ECOLI^KLEP7
2  NARG_ECOLI^NARG             <NA>
```

One possible solution is to visually inspect and make the selections in my data, but the actual table has dozens of columns and hundreds of rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.t <- data.t[grepl('ECOLI', data.t$ColA), ]
```

To obtain a staggered list of all instances of ECOLI in each column of `data.t`:

```
out <- lapply(data.t, grep, pattern='ECOLI', value=T)
```

If you want to drop 0 length entries.

```
nout <- sapply(out, length)
out <- out[nout > 0]
nout <- nout[nout > 0]
```

To merge that staggered list into a rectangular object like a data frame is unwise, but:

```
mapply(c, out, mapply(rep, NA, max(nout)-nout))
```

Comment: Thank you, AdamO. This works for the toy data, where you can easily locate ECOLI cells. Unfortunately I need something that can automate this subsetting routine for a larger table, and I need only cells containing ECOLI to be in the output.

Comment: @PedroDaPos I have edited my question since I believe I missed your original specifications. I don't think my previous answer worked for even your toy data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return ONLY the items in the data frame that have "ECOLI" in them, then here is a `tidyverse` approach

```
library(tidyverse)

filter_all(data.t, any_vars(grepl("ECOLI", .))) %>% 
 .[map_lgl(.,  ~any(grepl("ECOLI", .x)))] %>% 
  map_df(~replace(.x, !grepl("ECOLI", .x), NA_character_))

   # A tibble: 2 x 2
              ColA             ColC
            <fctr>           <fctr>
1 NARG_ECOLI^Q:103             <NA>
2  NARG_ECOLI^NARG NARG_ECOLI^KLEP7
```

Comment: @PedroDaPos IMO, solution has worked. The values shown in result are expected values. Seems example is wrong in OP

Answer (score 0):

I tried solving this using `base` functions.

```
# Data
data.t <- data.frame(ColA = c("NARG_ECOLI^Q:103", "NARG_ECOLI^NARG",
"SPEB_KLEP7^Q:103"), ColB = c(NA, NA, NA), ColC = c("KLEP7^Q:103", 
"NARG_ECOLI^KLEP7", NA), ColD = c("RPOC_ENTFA^Q:2", NA, NA), ColE = 
c("Y1546_STAS1^Q:6", NA, NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# First wrote a function to check cell value. If value contains
 "ECOLI" then value # of cell is retained else value is replaced with NA
findECOLI <- function(x){
    ifelse(grepl("ECOLI", x, fixed = TRUE), x, NA)
}

d1 <- sapply(data.t,  findECOLI)

#> d1
#     ColA               ColB ColC               ColD ColE
#[1,] "NARG_ECOLI^Q:103" NA   NA                 NA   NA  
#[2,] "NARG_ECOLI^NARG"  NA   "NARG_ECOLI^KLEP7" NA   NA  
#[3,] NA                 NA   NA                 NA   NA 

# Now, remove the rows containing only NA
d1 <- d1[rowSums(is.na(d1)) != ncol(d1), ]
#> d1
#     ColA               ColB ColC               ColD ColE
#[1,] "NARG_ECOLI^Q:103" NA   NA                 NA   NA  
#[2,] "NARG_ECOLI^NARG"  NA   "NARG_ECOLI^KLEP7" NA   NA

# Remove the columns containing only NA
d1 <- d1[, colSums(is.na(d1)) != nrow(d1)]

#Result:
#>d1
#     ColA               ColC              
#[1,] "NARG_ECOLI^Q:103" NA                
#[2,] "NARG_ECOLI^NARG"  "NARG_ECOLI^KLEP7"
```